# How to handle csrf token when session is expired

Tags: angularjs, session, laravel-4

When a user is logged in and the session is expired (Laravel) there's a 401 intercepter in Angular which redirects the user to the login page.
The login page has a Laravel-filter which checks for a csrf token but when loggin back in there's a token mismatch. I need to inject/get a new CSRF-token from Laravel.

Anyone has any ideas how to work around this problem?

I inject the token via:

```
  <script>angular.module('trackr').constant('CSRF_TOKEN', {
    _token: '<?= csrf_token(); ?>'
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Why have a CSRF-token filter in login page ?

Comment: Only the POST-request on the login. But it still uses the old/injected token.

Comment: Still, it makes no sense to check the CSRF token on the login page, because by definition there will be no token or the token will be expired. (BTW, I don't think a CSRF token should be used as an Auth token...)

Comment: But you should always protect login forms from CSRF-attacks?

Comment: If you don't use CSRF token fro authentication you can issue a new one when visiting login.

Comment: @ExpertSystem - when you visit the 'getLogin' page, you will be given a new session, which includes a CSRF token. You dont have to be 'logged in' to have a session. So having CSRF protection on the 'postLogin' page is correct.

Comment: This entry is misleading in that it makes it seem that you don't need CSRF tokens on the login page. Should mention an attack called the Login CSRF, where the user is logged into the account of the attacker: https://support.detectify.com/customer/portal/articles/1969819-login-csrf